# Selenium IDE regex gives error "Threw an exception: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: selenium

In my test case I am trying to capture the dynamic state id from the url of current web page.

My Selenium IDE code is:

```
storeLocation | myLocation

echo | ${myLocation}
myLocation returns https://stage.abcx.com/ui/States/ManageTitle.ddx?      action=view&stateid=76702 

storeEval | re=/^sid/;re.exec(${myLocation}) | new

echo | ${new}
```

The error I keep getting is

[error] Threw an exception: missing ) after argument list

I have searched the net to find what's wrong with my code but could not figure out the issue.

Am new to Selenium and regex would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace

```
storeEval | re=/^sid/;re.exec(${myLocation}) | new
```

with:

```
storeEval | /\\d*$/.exec(storedVars['myLocation']) | new
```

`new` will contain all last digits from `myLocation`. Some info about the difference between ${x} and storedVars['x'] can be found [here](http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2008/03/selenium-ide-test-tips.html).